# Spring SAML Extension strips of query string param for Single Sign on Service

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

Spring SAML Extension seem to disregard the query string param configured in IDP xml. Here is the configuration

```
   <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://<provier host>/saml/?query1=xxx&amp;query2=yyy"/>
```

1) When the SSO request gets redirected, SAML extension seem to strip anything after ? and send only SAMLRequest query string param.

2) Also I wanted modify query string param value based on some configuration so that I can hit environment specific endpoints for testing and development

Is there a way to intercept the redirection request before the redirection to satisfy the above needs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The query parameters are removed by the underlaying OpenSAML library in class `org.opensaml.saml2.binding.encoding.HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder`. You can extend this class, override method `buildRedirectURL` and add parameters as you need to the constructed URL. Your implementation would then need to be added to bean `org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding` using its constructor which accepts instances of `MessageDecoder` and `MessageEncoder`.

Comment: Thanks. I was debugging on it and found that OpenSAML library strips of the query string after I posted the question. I also tried to update the url through samlmessagecontext.getPeerEntityRoleMetadata().getEndpoints() and then singlesignon service but it did not work. I am going to try the solution that you suggested here.

Comment: This did not work for me trying to override the HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder with a new HttpRedirectDeflateBinding bean with a high prescedence. I posted my effort in SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48551925/saml-http-request-intercept-with-spring-boot

Overriding the bean doesn't seem to take affect and adding the query params in the Idp metadata continue to get stripped

Answer (score 0):

Hit this exact issue with the new Google Apps SAML IDP Federated SSO.
Vladimír's suggestion above helped me solve the problem.
Here is the exact error I was getting to enable others to find the solution.

```
400. That’s an error.

Invalid Request, no idpId in request URL, check if SSO URL is configured properly on SP side. That’s all we know.
```